# Regex pattern to capture numbers only, but only on single line

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

This regex pattern that will match 15 consecutive numbers, optionally with non-digits interspersed:

`\d(?:\D?\d){14}(?!\d)`

Here is my sample data showing four valid matches:

```
Correct matches: #19-04-052-320-008-55,19 04 052 320 008 75,19/04/052/320/0/0/8/8/0, 190405232000895
```

The problem arises when there are digits across multiple lines.  My regex will match the multi-line string below:

```
Incorrect match:
12
950,500
345
817,430
67
```

How can I modify the current pattern so that it **will not** match 15 consecutive numbers when they are spread over multiple lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\b\d(?:[^\n\d]*\d){14}(?!\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ugGq8/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Matches a word boundary so that first match digit is matched in a separate word
- `[^\n\d]*`: Matches 0 or more of any char that is not a digit and not a line break
- `(?:[^\n\d]*\d){14}`: Matches 14 digits optionally interspersed by 0 or more non-digits, non-line breaks